# Display an element after a block line brea

Tags: html, css

**I currently have this :**
[image]

And I want to put the icon div at the end of the text, but because it a 'block' I can't make it work.

**Output wanted :**
[image]

**Code snippet :**

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, 'sans-serif'
}

.test {
  display: flex;
}

.info {
  font-family: 'monospace';
  background: black;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada.     Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
   <div class="info">i</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why were you using flex? That's half of what caused the problem, but removing it - obviously - has consequences, but those depend entirely on your intent with your code.

Comment: I thought I could figure something with `flex` properties. But indeed, removing it and adding an inline-block to the icon solved the issue.

Comment: The benefit of experience! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove `display: flex` from the container (`.test`)
2. Make the info icon (`.info`) as `inline-block` with `display: inline-block`

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, 'sans-serif'
}

.info {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'monospace';
  background: black;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada.     Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
   <div class="info">i</div>
</div>
```